# Aurelia and the dreaded commonJs.convert: COULD NOT CONVERT error

Tags: aurelia

Background info:
Aurelia CLI
npm version 3.10.3
node version 6.7.0

Project was created and initially developed by me. Checked in to the customer's git repository. While I was assigned to other tasks, a couple of my co-workers continued working on the project. I'm now back working on this project and the first thing I did was a `git pull`. After updating my local copy of the source files, etc., I ran `au build` which produced the following error:

```
commonJs.convert: COULD NOT CONVERT:  
C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/selectedcustomer.js, so skipping it.  
Error  was:  Error: Line 1: Unexpected token  
        { uid: 8,
          name: 'writeBundles',
          branch: false,
          error:  { Error: Parse error using esprima for file: C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/selectedcustomer.js
                    Error: Line 1: Unexpected token
                    at Object.context.load (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodrotrace\lib\loade\Loader.js:379:19)  
                    at Object.load (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0),<anonymous>:832:29)
                    at Object.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:822:66)
                    at Object.check (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:854:30)
                    at Object.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1173:22)
                    at Object.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1554:39)
                    at Object.context.enable (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:289:24)
                    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0),<anonymous>:1158:33)
                    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:134:23)
                    at each (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:59:31)
          moduleTree: [ 'app' ],  
          fileName: 'C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/app.js' },
          duration: [ 0, 514590053 ],  
          time: 1486381456095  
        }
        { uid: 0,
          name: '<series>',
          branch: true,
          error: { Error: Parse error using esprima for file: C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/selectedcustomer.js
          Error: Line 1: Unexpected token
                   at Object.context.load (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:379:19)
                   at Object.load (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:832:29)
                   at Object.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:822:66)
                   at Object.check (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:854:30)
                   at Object.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1173:22)
                   at Object.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1554:39)
                   at Object.context.enable (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:289:24)
                   at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1158:33)
                   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:134:23)
                   at each (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:59:31) 
          moduleTree: [ 'app' ],      
          fileName: 'C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/app.js' },
          duration: [ 11, 848277505 ], 
          time: 1486381456113 }
{ Error: Parse error using esprima for file: C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/selectedcustomer.js
  Error: Line 1: Unexpected token
    at Object.context.load (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:379:19)
    at Object.load (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:832:29)
    at Object.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:822:66)
    at Object.check (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:854:30)
    at Object.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1173:22)
    at Object.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1554:39)
    at Object.context.enable (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:289:24)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1158:33)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0), <anonymous>:134:23)
    at each (eval at <anonymous> (C:\repos\xxxxxx\FrontEnd\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:1:0),<anonymous>:59:31)
moduleTree: [ 'app' ],
fileName: 'C:/repos/xxxxxx/FrontEnd/src/app.js' }
```

Is there someone out there who knows what could be causing this? It builds on my co-workers machines so I'm genuinely at loss as to why I get this error.  Also, as long as this isn't resolved I'm not able to work on the project, something my customer isn't too happy about.

Btw, I have tried `npm install` to no avail.

TIA

--norgie

Comment: When you pull down the git repo, do you have a file `selectedCustomer.js` at the location the error seems to be expecting it in?

Comment: Yes, there is a file called `selectedcustomer.js` at `/FrontEnd/src/`.

Comment: Sorry. I was mistaken. Turns out the file is called `SelectedCustomer.js`. So my co-worker who introduced the file (and class) had named the file `SelectedCustomer.js` instead of `selectedcustomer.js` thereby breaking our js-files naming convention, It was then referenced as `selectedcustomer`when importing the class. Changing the file name seems to fix the problem. Thx for pointing me in the right direction. Imagine if we could have a js parser that could have produced a sensible error message like e.g. `File not found...` instead of the "gibberish" above. One can always hope I guess.

Comment: I don't disagree about the error message. glad I could help. I assumed that was the issue and was puzzled when you said the file was there :)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use any lint plugins with the Aurelia CLI?

Comment: I have the same issue, except that the files does actually exist. I triple-checked (and the error message gives an absolute path, so it's an easy thing to check). I would agree that this error message clearly isn't explicit enough... any idea what I can do to find out more about this issue ?